# How do I turn on the webview autocomplete for an login form in Ionic's capacitor in iOS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic4, capacitor

I want to know how to enable the autocomplete for a login form in Capacitor (or if it's possible).  I'm using Ionic React.  It works if access the page in Safari on iOS and even if you pin it to the home screen.  But if you bundle the web app in Capacitor, the autocomplete is not there.  Here's the code for the login form:

```
<form onSubmit={e => loginAndCloseModal({e, emailValue, passwordValue})}>
  <IonList>
    <IonItem>
      <IonLabel position="stacked">Email</IonLabel>
      <IonInput autocomplete="username" name="email" value={emailValue} onIonChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}></IonInput>
    </IonItem>
    <IonItem>
      <IonLabel position="stacked">Password</IonLabel>
      <IonInput autocomplete="current-password" name="password" type="password" value={passwordValue} onIonChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}></IonInput>
    </IonItem>
    { errorMessage &&
        <IonItem>
          <IonNote color="danger">{errorMessage}</IonNote>
        </IonItem> }
  </IonList>
  <IonButton class="login-button" expand="block" type="submit" disabled={authLoading}>Login</IonButton>
</form>
```

I've also tried setting `autocomplete="on"` as well and it didn't work.  Apple's documentation recommends using the values posted above: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element

Here's a screenshot of the login page on the web:

[image: web version of login form]

Here's a version of the login form in Capacitor:

[image: capacitor version of login form]

Notice the passwords option in the above the keyboard is gone. Why is that?

Here's the relevant dependencies of my project:

```
"@capacitor/cli": "^1.2.1",
"@capacitor/core": "^1.2.1",
"@capacitor/ios": "^1.2.1",
"@ionic/react": "^4.11.2",
"@ionic/react-router": "^4.11.2",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
```

I'm using iOS version 12.4.2

EDIT:

I've done some more research.  There [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/) documentation from Apple.
The relevant section is this:

> Enable Password AutoFill
>
> Password AutoFill uses heuristics to determine when the user logs in
>   or creates new passwords, and automatically provides the password
>   QuickType bar. These heuristics give users some Password AutoFill
>   support in most apps, even if those apps haven’t been updated to
>   support AutoFill. However, to provide the best user experience and
>   ensure your app fully supports Password AutoFill, perform the
>   following steps:
>
> 1. Set up your app’s associated domains. To learn how to set up your app’s associated domains, see Setting Up an App’s Associated Domains.
> 2. Set the correct AutoFill type on relevant text fields. For an iOS app, see Enabling Password AutoFill on a Text Input View. For a web
>      app, see Enabling Password AutoFill on an HTML Input Element.

I did 2 from above when I first asked this question, but not 1.  However after doing number 1 it's still not working.

[Here's some more relevant documentation from Apple.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow)

Comment: Take a look at this thread. I believe if there is a working answer on how to autofill login details without having to search for them it will show up here. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-autofill-password-on-ios/199744/28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19478#issuecomment-559081576

Basically don't wrap any of your input fields in an ion-item tag, use div instead (for example).

The corresponding WebKit bug report is this: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203299

Comment: That is not really a workaround, as you can not use stacked or floating labels anymore

Comment: Do you know if this affects all input fields or just email/password?

Answer (score 4):

1. First, log into the [Apple Developer](http://%20https://developer.apple.com/account/) site. Navigate to the “Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles” section and select your app’s identifier. Note the `App ID prefix` and `Bundle ID`, and under Capabilities, toggle “Associated Domains” then save.
2. Then, create a file on your web server called `apple-app-site-association`. This file will be configured in JSON format, but it is **not allowed to have a .json or any other extension**.
3. Paste the following content inside the file and edit the marked places.

   Replace `XXXXXXXXXX` with the App ID prefix and `com.example` with
   the Bundle ID of the app.

   ```
   {
     "webcredentials": {
       "apps": [
         "XXXXXXXXXX.com.example" // Replace this
       ]
     },
     "applinks": {
       "apps": [], // needs to be empty
       "details": [
         {
           "appID": "XXXXXXXXXX.com.example", // This too
           "paths": [
             "*"
           ]
         }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
4. After that, make sure this file is accessible via the route https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association.
5. Also make sure that your server uses https
6. It is also necessary to specify the content type for this file. It needs to be `application/pkcs7-mime`. This can be done, for example, using Website Headers. At the hosting provider [Render.com](https://render.com) it looks like this, for example:

[image: Example Website Header configuration on render.com]

- Request path: `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`
- Header name: `Content-Type`
- Header value; `application/pkcs7-mime`

7. Now you have to open the `ios/` folder in XCode. You can do this manually or by using the command `npx cap open ios`. There you click on `App` in the left side bar and then again on `App` under `Targets`. Then select the `Signing & Capabilities` tab.
8. Add a new Associated Domains Capability and then add the domain `applinks:example.com` for Deep Link support and `webcredentials:example.com` for auto-populating passwords. Replace `example.com` with the domain name of your website.

> **Edit:** I have also added the `Autofill Credential Provider` capability.

If nothing has changed, then everything should work now. Otherwise, here are a few helpful links that have helped me:

- [Capacitor – Deep Linking with Universal and App Links](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links)
- [Setting up iOS Universal Links](https://gist.github.com/anhar/6d50c023f442fb2437e1)
- [How to Setup Universal Links in Ionic (iOS & Android)](https://devdactic.com/universal-links-ionic/)
- [Enabling Password AutoFill on an HTML Input Element](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element)
- [Universal Link Validator](https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com)

Answer (score 1):

after search along I found this way to autofill password functionality in ionic 5 / capacitor.

first, need to must set up your app’s associated domains.
check this link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

after that use this npm package for IOS.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-ios-autofill-save-password

its help save password functionality.

Comment: This worked for me too! Do you know how to achieve the same for android?

Comment: @user3698965 for android needs to use local storage. or try with ionic input autocomplete. Maybe it worked...
[https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#autocomplete]

Comment: This works for me in that it saves the login details in the keychain.  But it does not offer to autofill them next time I try to log in. I am using autocomplete="username" and autocomplete="current-password". Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, @MadMac try without autocomplete, only with email/username and password.

Answer (score 1):

A guide has been written for implementing autofill of credentials with Capacitor:
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/autofill-credentials

This also covers troubleshooting common mistakes and errors.

Comment: Thanks for providing this, I will try to implement it and report back

Comment: While the link provided may answer the question, its always better to include in your answer itself the main points of the link. Also Please Read [How do i write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything as well, name=username or name=current-password, autocomplete="current-password" and autocomplete="username", autocomplete="on", etc. I can get the Password button on the keyboard to display only in the Password field, allow me to select a prior saved account (User Name, Password, Web Site), but it only fills in the password not the username field.

So try to go into setting Password & Accounts, turn on AutoFill Password "Green", then Website & App Passwords, and input account info.

But I have two outstanding issues, 1.) will not prompt me for username autocomplete in the username field. 2.) has no domain for my app to related the account to my app. This technically odd... the issue seems to be within the Ionic Framework; Ionic 4.

**References:**

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element

**System:**
   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)

Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.7.1

@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9

@angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9

@angular/cli                  : 7.3.9

@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

**IOS:**

12.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, seems to work if you just keep the IonInput, and not wrap it within an IonItem.