# Ionic autofill password iOS keychain for native builds

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

How can I save passwords for iOS and probably android so I have the autofill or the native iOS password from... keychain functionality shown in the keyboard, like:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow

I have found this ionic plugin:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/keychain-touch-id/
but I am not sure is this one what I need, because I don't want to use touch id or face id at all. Just want to be able to store passwords, so next time they login with the email paired they got the password hint in the native iOS keyboard AccessoryBar so they can just use the password from their keychian.

Autofill works fine for Ionic web apps but not for the native ones.

Comment: Did you solved?

Comment: I've been using the keychain-touch-id, but then I removed it. So, not exactly.

Comment: Maybe my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67970502/7878273 can help you.