# Ionic 4 & capacitor, How to Autofill password on ios?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ios14, capacitor

I got a app on applestore, it use ionic 4 & capacitor. But i can't save id password in the first time login and update it.
I try

- add  Associated Domain file on domain
  (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains)
- add Associated Domain for app by xcode
- add Capabilities Associated Domains on Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
  But when app run, look. When i credentials info account & password and login. Nothing, not has a pop-up ask you whether you want to save these login details to your iCloud Keychain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I turn on the webview autocomplete for an login form in Ionic's capacitor in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530929/how-do-i-turn-on-the-webview-autocomplete-for-an-login-form-in-ionics-capacitor)